# Connection made via sakis3g not recognised by software center

Tags: software-center, internet, deb, 3g

I have used sakis3g to connect to internet as network manager is not able to make a connection although it recognizes the modem.But the problem is many software including pidgin and software center doesn't know that computer is already connected to internet and I am having problems installing software especially the debs I downloaded. Although I can still download and install packages from terminal.

So is there any way I can make software center recognize this connection?

or

can I install debs in some other alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu software center depend on the network manager to detect online status.So If you are connecting to internet without network-manager ,you have to quit it,

Open theterminal and type
    `sudo stop network-manager`

It solves the problem

Comment: You can expand your answer to explain how or why this resolves the Ops question.  Also your solution may have a broader impact that prevents other capabilities on their machine.  You may wish to point these out.